# How to create area around value?

Tags: r

Sorry, probably my question is not so clear, because I can not formulate it. I wiil explain by example.

I have two dataframes`df` and `df1`:

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(25,15,35,45,2))
df1 <- data.frame(b = c(28,25,24,43,10))
```

I want to merge two dataframes with condition if values == +-5 and create column `distance`. For example, first element in column `a` is 25, I want to compare 25 with all elements in column `b`, and I want to select only 25 == +- 25. The output should look like:

```
   a     b     distance
   25    28    3
         24    1
         25    0
   15    10    5
   45    43    2
```

And values which are not equal +- 5 should be excluded like 2 and 35.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use `outer` to create a logical matrix, get the row/column index with `which` and `arr.ind = TRUE`.  Use the index to subset the 'a', and 'b' column from corresponding datasets and get the `diff`erence`

```
i1 <- which(outer(df$a, df1$b, FUN = function(x, y) 
        abs(x - y) <=5), arr.ind = TRUE)
transform(data.frame(a = df$a[i1[,1]], b = df1$b[i1[,2]]), distance = abs(a - b))
```

-output

```
   a  b distance
1 25 28        3
2 25 25        0
3 25 24        1
4 45 43        2
5 15 10        5
```